# Database of Press Releases

Tags: business, corpora, journalism, news

Is there a corpus of business/corporate press releases? I'm looking for a collection of releases like these, but from any corporation whatsoever: http://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20161209005816/en/IMPORTANT-INVESTOR-ALERT-Goldberg-Law-PC-Announces.

Specifically, I only care about English texts.

Comment: I also am interested in this in order to analyze releases from all companies in a sector.  The answer below works for a specific company, but I'd like to do an analysis of releases from thousands of companies.  The PR companies have archives of their own releases, but I'm looking for a consolidated set.

Answer (score 1):

Most publicly traded companies (and some private ones) will keep a list of recent press releases on their website. Sometimes Yahoo Finance, when "covering" a publicly traded company, will compile a useful list of news articles.